# Parsing Wikipedia table with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, wikipedia

I am new to Python and recently started exploring web crawling. The code below parses [the S&P 500 List Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies) and writes the data of a specific table into a database.

While this script is hardcoded and I would certainly be interested in some thoughts on performing the same task in a slightly more generic way (perhaps with `beautifulsoup`), this is not my primary concern. What I really wondered was if there is a less verbose or more "pythonic" way of doing it.

```
import urllib.request
import re
import pymysql

# Open Website and get only the table on the page with the relevant data. In this hardcoded case 
table = urllib.request.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies#S.26P_500_Component_Stocks").read().decode("utf-8")
table = table.split("<table")[1]
table = table.split("\n")

# Define regex used for parsing and initialise list containers
tick_ident_nasdaq = 'href=\"http:\/\/www\.nasdaq\.com\/symbol\/'
tick_ident_nyse = 'href=\"https:\/\/www.nyse.com\/quote\/'
name_grab = '\">(.+)<\/a></td>'
cigs_grab = '^<td>(.+)</td>'

ticker, exchange, names, cigs, cigs_sub = ( [] for i in range(5))
match = False           

# Parse HTML output and write relevant td data to lists. 
# The list is "hardcoded", meaning after each match of either NASDAQ or NYSE ident, 
# the matching <td> as well as the next, the fourth and fifth <td> after that one get parsed.  

for i in range(len(table)):
    if bool(re.search(pattern = tick_ident_nasdaq, string = table[i])):
        ticker.append(re.search(pattern = name_grab, string = table[i]).group(1))
        exchange.append("NASDAQ")
        match = True

    elif bool(re.search(pattern = tick_ident_nyse, string = table[i])):
        ticker.append(re.search(pattern = name_grab, string = table[i]).group(1))
        exchange.append("NYSE")
        match = True

    if match == True:
        names.append(re.search(pattern = name_grab, string = table[i + 1]).group(1))
        names[-1] = re.sub(pattern = "&amp;", repl = "&", string = names[-1])
        cigs.append(re.search(pattern = cigs_grab, string = table[i + 3]).group(1))
        cigs[-1] = re.sub(pattern = "&amp;", repl = "&", string = cigs[-1])
        cigs_sub.append(re.search(pattern = cigs_grab, string = table[i + 4]).group(1))
        cigs_sub[-1] = re.sub(pattern = "&amp;", repl = "&", string = cigs_sub[-1])
        match = False

# Format Data in tuple format for database export
company_data = zip(ticker, exchange, names, cigs, cigs_sub)

# Establish database connection, empty companies table and rewrite list data to table    
try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "pw", db = "db", charset = "utf8", autocommit = True, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM companies")
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO companies (tickersymbol, exchange, name, cigs, cigs_sub) VALUES (\"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\")", (company_data))   
finally:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The right tool**

As you've said, you are not using the right tool for this task : you [can't parse HTML with regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

A better approach would be to use an already existing parser like BeautifulSoup.

**A simpler container**

At the moment, you are putting data in multiple lists to zip them all at the very end. It can be a very nice technique but in our case, you put in different containers things that actually belong together. Also, you have a risk of adding too many elements in a list and having information zipped with information that should be in a different row. An easier option is to have a single list where each elements contain everything you've parsed.

Also, you can take this chance to rewrite in a more straightforward way the parts where you add something a list and then refer to it with `my_list[-1]`.

```
company_data = []

for i in range(len(table)):
    if bool(re.search(pattern = tick_ident_nasdaq, string = table[i])):
        exchange = "NASDAQ"
    elif bool(re.search(pattern = tick_ident_nyse, string = table[i])):
        exchange = "NYSE"
    else:
        exchange = None
    if exchange:
        ticker = re.search(pattern = name_grab, string = table[i]).group(1)
        name = re.search(pattern = name_grab, string = table[i + 1]).group(1)
        name = re.sub(pattern = "&amp;", repl = "&", string = name)
        cig = re.search(pattern = cigs_grab, string = table[i + 3]).group(1)
        cig = re.sub(pattern = "&amp;", repl = "&", string = cig)
        cig_sub = re.search(pattern = cigs_grab, string = table[i + 4]).group(1)
        cig_sub = re.sub(pattern = "&amp;", repl = "&", string = cig_sub)
        company_data.append((ticker, exchange, name, cig, cig_sub))
```

**Compile your regexp**

You can compile regexp if you plan to reuse them many times. It is more efficient and it makes it possible to use them like any Python object.

```
# Define regex used for parsing
tick_ident_nasdaq = re.compile('href=\"http:\/\/www\.nasdaq\.com\/symbol\/')
tick_ident_nyse = re.compile('href=\"https:\/\/www.nyse.com\/quote\/')
name_grab = re.compile('\">(.+)<\/a></td>')
cigs_grab = re.compile('^<td>(.+)</td>')
amp_re = re.compile("&amp;")

company_data = []

for i in range(len(table)):
    if bool(tick_ident_nasdaq.search(string = table[i])):
        exchange = "NASDAQ"
    elif bool(tick_ident_nyse.search(string = table[i])):
        exchange = "NYSE"
    else:
        exchange = None
    if exchange:
        ticker = name_grab.search(string = table[i]).group(1)
        name = name_grab.search(string = table[i + 1]).group(1)
        name = amp_re.sub(repl = "&", string = name)
        cig = cigs_grab.search(string = table[i + 3]).group(1)
        cig = amp_re.sub(repl = "&", string = cig)
        cig_sub = cigs_grab.search(string = table[i + 4]).group(1)
        cig_sub = amp_re.sub(repl = "&", string = cig_sub)
        company_data.append((ticker, exchange, name, cig, cig_sub))
```

**"&" and "&"**

What you are trying to do when substituing "&" with "&":

- deserves to but put in a function on its own
- actually corresponds to a common problem already solved : [HTML entity decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string).

Comment: Nice read about Regex parsing on the link, looks like I still have a lot of basics to learn.  Thanks for the improvements, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic approach here could be to use [`pandas.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) function that can parse this table into a `DataFrame` which would be very convenient to deal with later - filter, slice, write to a database (see [`to_sql()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)).

Here is a sample code to get the desired S&P 500 dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
response = requests.get(url)

df = pd.read_html(response.content)[0]
print(df)
```

And, FYI, `read_html()` is using `BeautifulSoup` for HTML parsing under-the-hood.

Comment: Wow, I'm currently doing some Pandas courses on the side, but I did not know about the HTML parsing features. Thanks!